# HiveSQL Alter table renames column and does not move data

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table with 100's of columns. I would like to move a column within this table to a new position.

For example my table (named "sample_table") looks like:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4
w,    x,    y,    z
```

Essentially I want to create a table that looks like:

```
var1, var2, var4, var3
w,    x,    z,    y
```

I have tried using:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table CHANGE var3
var3 STRING AFTER var4
```

But I get:

```
var1, var2, var4, var3
w,    x,    y,    z
```

So all I have achieved is to rename the last column without moving the data in that column.

I know I could write a create table statement and use the select statement within this to put the columns in the order needed. However this seems very inefficient when I have 100's of columns and just need to move one column within the entire table.

How would I go about moving the whole column and not just rename it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple statements:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table CHANGE var3 var3_ STRING;
ALTER TABLE sample_table CHANGE var4 var3 STRING;
ALTER TABLE sample_table CHANGE var3_ var4 STRING;
```

Comment: This will just rename the columns rather than moving the entire column including the data.

Comment: @Pete Are you using `SELECT *`? Why does even order of columns matter?